# AsyncTask updates data after fragment is shown

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have fragment that displays data about user downloaded from web service. I want to download that data after the fragment is shown, just like some applications do. While there's no data avaliable, I would like to use either some default value or ProgressBar. What is the proper way to do this? Should I call asyncTask in onCreate or onCreateView method? (since it's not  clear if this fragment will be ever shown)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the on create method. You want the dialog to begin in the doInBackground method of the Async task and hide the dialog in the on post execute method where you update your view depending on what information you get back.